# How to do zero padding to a hexadecimal number converted from int?

Tags: c++

I am printing converted hexadecimal values like the following:

```
std::cout << std::hex << integers[i] << " "; //i is a loop counter
```

But it prints out single digits for few values, like `FF D2 78 9 A9 87 f ff`. I want those single values to have a 0: `FF D2 78 09 A9 87 0f ff`.

I tried

```
if(integers[i] == 1 || ... || integers[i] = (int)'f')
{
std::cout << "0" << std::hex << integers[i] << " ";
}
```

But when 1 ... f is an hexadecimal value it, it does not print properly. How can I convert the value to hex first and check if its one digit or two digits and add 0 padding if it is a single digit?

Comment: maybe you want `std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << integers[i] << " ";` ?

Comment: Worked perfectly. thanks

Comment: @M.M that should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: integers[i] = (int)'f'   won't work.

Comment: If you are going to test the values manually (which is not needed), you would need something more like this instead `if ((integers[i] >= 0) && (integers[i] < 16)) { std::cout << "0"; } cout << std::hex << integers[i] << " ";`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wasn't sure if that was what's being asked